# OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded after Updating gradle plugin in android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0, build-time

I am having problem with gradle after updating my project to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
It was previously working with com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3.
I have already tweak my memory setting which is located in gradle.properties.

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5120m -XX:MaxPermSize=3230m-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

But still getting the following error

```
>     The system is out of resources.
>     Consult the following stack trace for details.
>     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.util.IntHashTable.rehash(IntHashTable.java:175)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.util.IntHashTable.putAtIndex(IntHashTable.java:146)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser$SimpleEndPosTable.storeEnd(JavacParser.java:4122)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser$SimpleEndPosTable.toP(JavacParser.java:4132)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.toP(JavacParser.java:557)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term3(JavacParser.java:1252)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term2(JavacParser.java:909)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term1(JavacParser.java:880)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:836)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:816)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.unannotatedType(JavacParser.java:810)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration(JavacParser.java:3518)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classOrInterfaceBody(JavacParser.java:3436)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classDeclaration(JavacParser.java:3285)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classOrInterfaceOrEnumDeclaration(JavacParser.java:3226)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration(JavacParser.java:3486)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classOrInterfaceBody(JavacParser.java:3436)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classDeclaration(JavacParser.java:3285)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classOrInterfaceOrEnumDeclaration(JavacParser.java:3226)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.typeDeclaration(JavacParser.java:3215)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseCompilationUnit(JavacParser.java:3155)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:628)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:665)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:950)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:892)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:921)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1187)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
>     
>      FAILED
>     :app:buildInfoGeneratorSimDebug
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines in **gradle.properties** file

> org.gradle.daemon=true
>
> org.gradle.configureondemand=true
>
> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Answer (score -1):

you can try this.

```
 android {
            compileSdkVersion 25
            buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
            applicationId "yourpackage"
            minSdkVersion 10
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can also try by decreasing classpath version

Comment: The thing is i would like to make use of the new gradle feature so
my app is working fine with the old gradle version